# Django Rest Framework serializer representation not working

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization

I'm following the Django Rest Framework [tutorial on serializers](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/1-serialization/), but finding some unusual behavior. Where print repr(serializer_instance) is apparently supposed to print useful inspection, I can only get back this representation:

```
<snippets.serializers.SnippetSerializer object at 0x10220f110>.
```

[My code](https://github.com/OldGareBear/django_rest_framework_tutorial) seems to line up exactly with that in the tutorial, and I'm using Django 1.7 and Python 2.7. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

snippets/serializers.py:

```
from django.forms import widgets
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES

class SnippetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'code', 'linenos', 'language', 'style')
```

snippets/models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from pygments.lexers import get_all_lexers
from pygments.styles import get_all_styles

LEXERS = [item for item in get_all_lexers() if item[1]]
LANGUAGE_CHOICES = sorted([(item[1][0], item[0]) for item in LEXERS])
STYLE_CHOICES = sorted((item, item) for item in get_all_styles())

class Snippet(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    code = models.TextField()
    linenos = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    language = models.CharField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python', max_length=100)
    style = models.CharField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly', max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('created',)
```

shell:

```
$ python manage.py shell_plus
>>> from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer
>>> serializer = SnippetSerializer()
>>> serializer
    <snippets.serializers.SnippetSerializer object at 0x10220f110>
>>> print repr(serializer)
    <snippets.serializers.SnippetSerializer object at 0x10220f110>
```

Comment: I am also not seeing the verbose "repr" output on my shell that the tutorial suggests we should be seeing--w/ Django 1.6, regardless of what serializer I use

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until I realized that I had version 2.4 installed.

Simply read the release notes and update to version 3.0

E.g. if you use a requirements.txt, change the rest framework line to :

```
djangorestframework==3.0
```

and run

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because you are returning the serializer object. In order to return the actual data you have to refer to the data attribute:

```
print repr(serializer.data)
```

Comment: That does show me the data (just like plain 'print serializer.data' does). But in the tutorial, 'repr(serializer)' is used to examine the serializer's schema--all of its column names, types, and validations. That's what I'm looking for